# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in dotnet framework version 4.8

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

We use dot-net framework version 4.8 when we provide HTTPS requests to extract data, receiving the error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" and set up SecurityProtocol as per the requirements.
Could you please help us to resolve the issues?

```
 public void SecurityProtocol(string protocol)
        {
            AllowAllHttpsTraffic();
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 0;
            var protocols = protocol.ToLower().Split(',');
            if (protocols.Contains("ssl3"))
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            if (protocols.Contains("tls"))
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
            if (protocols.Contains("tls11"))
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
            if (protocols.Contains("tls12"))
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol == 0)
                throw new Exception("One or more security protocols must be specified in a comma-delimited list. Ex: tls,tls11,tls12");
        }

 using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
                    {
                        contentType = DocHelpers.HtmlContent;
                        if (response.Headers["Content-Type"] != null)
                            contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
                    }

                    // Get the data from the response
                    _code.ExtractData(response, contentType);
```

We should be able to use extract data from HTTP and HTTPS requests without Issues.

Comment: "set up SecurityProtocol as per the requirements" don't do this, instead allow the operating system to define supported protocols. Also `HttpWebRequest` is way out of date, use `HttpClient` instead. But neither of those will fix your issue. Can you give us some more debugging, what is the full error message? What protocol are you trying to use, what protocol is the server using? Which version of Windows and .NET are both machines using? Can you do a Wireshark trace on the Server Hello and Client Hello, see if there is a cipher mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure that the client and server mutually support a level of secure communication at the operating system level?  For example if the server supports TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 but your client only supports TLS1.1 then communication cannot occur.